# Function Add with one variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, automation

I have a problem with my AMPscript.
I would like to use the function AMPscript Add to add differents price from different products that are also connected with the count AMPscript function
e.g.

```
%%[
var @rsorder, @roworder, @rsitem, @rowitem, @counterorder, @counteritem, @currentorder, @article_review_url,@size, @price
SET @rsorder = LOOKUPROWS("Abandon_Cart_ID", "customer_id",[customer_id])
for @counterorder = 1 to ROWCOUNT(@rsorder) do

    SET @currentorder = FIELD(ROW(@rsorder, @counterorder), "basket_id")
    SET @rsitem = LOOKUPROWS("Abandon_Cart_ITEMS", "basket_id", @currentorder)

    if ROWCOUNT(@rsitem) != 0 then

        for @counteritem = 1 to ROWCOUNT(@rsitem) do

            SET @rowitem = ROW(@rsitem, @counteritem)
            SET @url = FIELD(@rowitem, "article_link")
            SET @price = FIELD(@rowitem, "PRICE")
            SET @size = FIELD(@rowitem, "SIZE")

            if MOD(@counteritem, 2) == 0 and @counteritem != 1 then
]%%
```

So the formula is counting if there are more the one product and is insering the different variable inside the HTML so I cannot add together the differents price because it is finding only one price. (variable declared is @price)

Someone knows how I can solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is some of your code missing?  I'm not seeing the `Add()` function.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for replying. I would like to use the add function after the counting of all the items based on the price.
For example Price1+Price2+Price3,.. but the fact is that the prices are not fixed but variables @price.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to total the prices then something like this would work.

```
%%[
var @rsorder, @roworder, @rsitem, @rowitem, @counterorder, @counteritem, @currentorder, @article_review_url, @size, @price, @orderTotal

SET @rsorder = LOOKUPROWS("Abandon_Cart_ID", "customer_id",[customer_id])

for @counterorder = 1 to ROWCOUNT(@rsorder) do

    SET @currentorder = FIELD(ROW(@rsorder, @counterorder), "basket_id")
    SET @rsitem = LOOKUPROWS("Abandon_Cart_ITEMS", "basket_id", @currentorder)
    set @orderTotal = 0

    if ROWCOUNT(@rsitem) != 0 then

        for @counteritem = 1 to ROWCOUNT(@rsitem) do

            SET @rowitem = ROW(@rsitem, @counteritem)
            SET @url = FIELD(@rowitem, "article_link")
            SET @price = FIELD(@rowitem, "PRICE")
            SET @size = FIELD(@rowitem, "SIZE")
            set @orderTotal = add(@orderTotal, @price)

            if MOD(@counteritem, 2) == 0 and @counteritem != 1 then
]%%
```

Steps would be:

1. declare @orderTotal
2. initialize it to zero
3. add @price to @orderTotal